# How to highlight linearlayout borders when we click the button in android

Tags: android

I have two linearlayouts and one button in the UI. When I click the Button the linear layouts should be highlighted.

Comment: you may use styles for that..:)

Comment: I am a beginner to android. can you please explain clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a list_selector.xml file in drawable folder with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--  Active Row-->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="***HIGHLIGHT COLOR***" />
<!--  Inactive Row-->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="***DEFAULT COLOR***" />
<!--  Pressed Row -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="***HIGHLIGHT COLOR***" />
<!--  Selected Row (using d-pad) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="***HIGHLIGHT COLOR***" />
</selector>
```

after this in your main xml file set background for button and linear layout as @drawable/list_selector